# Is it possible to route to service secured with SSL?

Tags: java, ssl, routes, netflix-zuul, api-gateway

I have simple Zuul configuration:

```
zuul:
  routes:
    users:
      path: /myusers/**
      url: https://example.com/users_service
```

For example URL https://example.com/users_service needs certificate authentication. Is is to possible to configure .p12 certificate for this particular route ?

Comment: Can you provide some more details - route means do you want to redirect or invoke it? from server side or javascript?

Comment: @BhushanKarmarkar From server side i would like to redirect

Answer (score 0):

If you want to redirect to the https URL, then there should not be any issue.

After redirection, browser will have the control and it will take care of all the certificate negotiations.
Make sure you have installed the personal certificate (.p12) on your machine's 'personal' section of certificate store.
Browser will pick it up from there, will show you the pop-up before actually sending it to 'example.com'.

If you want to 'invoke' the https URL from the backend (like invoking REST and get the response back), then you will have to provide custom keystore to the java (keystore containing .p12 or you can directly use .p12 also).